# AS3: Adding 2 positive integers yield negative integer

Tags: actionscript-3, int, addition, integer-overflow

I was making a Pascal's triangle in AS3.

And in the results I find that, the addition of 1037158320 and 1166803110 yields -2091005866, a negative integer!

This is weird. I first thought that the magnitudes were too great for an `int` to hold, but the magnitude of the sum is even greater than the two addends.

And plus, as a number approaches the center of a line of a Pascal's triangle, it should increase, but the one next to -2091005866 was -1961361076, which is closer to the centerm but the magnitude decreases!

Any possible solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [ActionScript 3.0 Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/int.html):

> The int class lets you work with the data type representing a 32-bit
>   signed integer. The range of values represented by the int class is
>   -2,147,483,648 (-2^31) to 2,147,483,647 (2^31-1).

1037158320 + 1166803110 = 2203961430 which is greater than 2147483647.

Consider using [uint](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/uint.html) or [Number](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Number.html).

Comment: +1 for Number. In AS3 `Number` is capable of containing 64-bit integer precision, as well as a double-precision floating-point value.

Comment: You should avoid uint when using such large numbers here as well, since uint has a max value of 2^32-1 (4.2 billion) which isn't a whole lot when dealing with numbers that large. By comparison, Number has a max value of 1.79e+308

Comment: @Vesper, "In AS3 Number is capable of containing 64-bit integer precision" it's not full correct, Number is IEEE754 Double precision 64-bit so it keeps only 52 bit for the mantisa, so the maximum integer without loss in precision is 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFF = 4503599627370495

Comment: I checks the docs to be sure and the actual maximum integer is even 53 bit (0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFF = 9007199254740991) because of way the system store Double there is 1 additional bit )